# Making Google Annotation Chart from a Google Sheet Query

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I am having some trouble with a google annotation chart I am working on. I started with the example provided by [Google](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart) and then tried adjusting it through Fiddle to use data from a query of my [google sheets document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KVOMq2usUg-FRmfx9cnGgJVR-wQZ2oJcyufaIgcxzFw).

I feel like I have messed up either with the query itself, or with putting the results of the query into the chart and drawing it.

Any help would be much appreciated. My Javscript is included below.

```
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['annotationchart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


      function initialize() {
            var opts = {sendMethod: 'auto'};
  // Replace the data source URL on next line with your data source URL.
        var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KVOMq2usUg-FRmfx9cnGgJVR-wQZ2oJcyufaIgcxzFw', opts);

  // Optional request to return only column C and the sum of column B, grouped by C members.
            query.setQuery('select B, select G');

  // Send the query with a callback function.
            query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

            function handleQueryResponse(response) {

              if (response.isError()) {
               alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
                return;
  }

              var data = response.getDataTable();
        var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        var options = {
          displayAnnotations: false
        };

        chart.draw(data, options);        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

couple things...

1. the callback function specified doesn't exist
   change -- `drawChart` to -- `initialize`
   (added to `load` statement below instead of using -- `setOnLoadCallback`)
2. query for selecting columns is incorrect
   change -- `select B, select G` to -- `select B, G`
   (added to url below instead of using -- `query.setQuery`)

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: initialize,
  packages: ['annotationchart']
});

function initialize() {
  var opts = {sendMethod: 'auto'};
  // Replace the data source URL on next line with your data source URL.
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KVOMq2usUg-FRmfx9cnGgJVR-wQZ2oJcyufaIgcxzFw/gviz/tq?tq=select B,G', opts);

  // Send the query with a callback function.
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  var options = {
    displayAnnotations: false
  };

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for the help!